# how i can find private key from Y X Z

Tags: transactions, private-key, blockchain.info, ecdsa

How can I find the private key with X and Y and Z
in the transaction

i have this

('THE R VALUE is  :', '0cf435db180216f3aaa5c2cb8231cbccf2f6824fc0051396b45e4ab01bb0f5e3')
('THE S VALUE is  :', '7d91b1b9a89bdf099645742e1ab56f5a1776f20606807e71adf52bc74258e535')
('THE Z VALUE is  :', '72f02c7b7183b2777ae15ba6dd69b475d3c65c42b4a20231d1b9c66c6c501c67')
('THE PUBKEY is :', '04d4fb35c2cdb822644f1057e9bd07e3d3b0a36702662327ef4eb799eb219856d0fd884fce43082b73424a3293837c5f94a478f7bc4ec4da82bfb7e0b43fb218cc')

how i can fund private key

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate of your second question to the same effect.